# Update query and Connection property has not been initialized

Tags: c#, sql-server

i passed a value from form1 to form2 and used that value as a where condition however i cant seem to fix it. I'm updating a table btw. any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-MQKIBSK\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=inventory2;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataAdapter adptr = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataSet dt = new DataSet();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Text == "EDIT")
        {           
            cmd.CommandText = string.Format("Update Items Set (Barcode='" + txtcode.Text + "' ,Productname= '" + txtitemname.Text + "',Prices= '" + txtPrices.Text + "' ,Quantity= '" + txtquantity.Text + "' ,Brand= '" + txtbrand.Text + "',Expiry= '" + txtexpiry.Text + "',Description='" + txtdescription.Text + "' ,Critical= '" + txtcritical.Text + "' where Barcode  = '" + txtTry.Text + "')", cn);          
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Records Updated!");
            txtcode.Text = "";
            txtitemname.Text = "";
            txtPrices.Text = "";
            txtquantity.Text = "";
            txtbrand.Text = "";
            txtexpiry.Text = "";
            txtdescription.Text = "";
            txtcritical.Text = "";
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid");
        }
```

Comment: You are passing the connection to the String.Format call instead of assigning it to the command object.  And **please** use SqlParameters rather than string concatenation.

Comment: yes sir ill use paramaters. ive already added the "cmd.Connection = cn;" and now the new error is   "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Incorrect syntax near '('. on the executenonquery line.

Comment: You're getting that error because your SQL is not valid: the `set` group should not have brackets around it: `Update Items Set Barcode=`…

Answer (score 0):

I think the error message is clear enough, you have to assign the connection to the command which is going to be executed. But here you may face another big issue, ie., the SqlInjection because of this concatenated query text query, You have to use parameterization instead to avoid the injection, in short your code would be looks like the following:

```
string connectioStr = "Data Source=DESKTOP-MQKIBSK\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=inventory2;Integrated Security=True";
string querySQL = "Update Items Set Barcode=@Barcode,Productname=@Productname,Prices=@Prices,Quantity=@Quantity where Barcode = @condition";
// add more columns as you needed in the set
using (SqlConnection conSQL = new SqlConnection(connectioStr))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmdSQL.Connection = conSQL;
        cmdSQL.CommandText = querySQL;
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Barcode", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtcode.Text;
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Productname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtitemname.Text;
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Prices", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtPrices.Text;
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Quantity", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtquantity.Text;
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@condition", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtcode.Text;
        // Add all parameters specified in the query
        // use appropriate datatypes as per the type of columns
    }
}
```

You can specify the connection and query of the command at the time of initializing the command; in this case the command initialization would be like this:

```
SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(querySQL,conSQL);
```

Comment: Thanks sir ill change it to parameters